# Does this hold: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{-n}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty 2^{-n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it true that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{-n}$ is equal to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty 2^{-n}$ ?

If yes, will you please show how to get this equation?

Thank you.

Comment: You can just do the geometric series. Is this homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=k}^\infty 2^{-n}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{k-1}=2
$$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^n2^{-n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n2^{-n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n \Big|_{x=1/2}=2
$$
since
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n =x\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=x \, \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \right)'=x\,(\frac{1}{1-x})'=x\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}
$$

Comment: Sir, how did you do the computation after the word "since"?

Answer (score 2):

More generally, if $a_{n,k}$ are nonnegative real numbers, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^na_{nk}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_{n,k}$ as extended nonnegative real numbers. In fact, if $S=\{(n,k)\in(\mathbb Z^+)^2: 1\leq k\leq n\}$, then you can see that $S=\{(n,k)\in(\mathbb Z^+)^2: n\geq k\}$: simply draw this set on the cartesian plane, and observe that for given $k\in\mathbb Z^+$, the pairs in $S$ with second coordinate equal to $k$ are precisely those pairs with first coordinate $\geq k$. This change on the order of summation has nothing to do with your specific summands.

Comment: Nice answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

Let's look more generally at 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n f(n,k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty f(n,k)
$$
to see that it holds. We can see the double sums as summing the entry in the following matrix:
$$
n\left\{ \overbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
f(1,1)&0&0&0&\cdots\\
f(2,1)&f(2,2)&0&0&\cdots\\
f(3,1)&f(3,2)&f(3,3)&0&\cdots\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots
\end{pmatrix}}^k \right.
$$
The left hand side sums the entry of the matrix  row by row, while the right hand side sums them column by column.

Answer (score 2):

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{-n}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty 2^{-n}
\quad ?$

Define $\Theta_{m,n} = 1$ if $m \geq n$ and $\Theta_{m,n} = 0$ if $m < n$.
\begin{align}
\color{#ff0000}{\large\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{-n}}
&=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\Theta_{n,k}
=
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\Theta_{n,k}
=
\color{#ff0000}{\large\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}2^{-n}}
\end{align}

Comment: This is the best explanation.  Note that it is common, following Knuth, to write $\Theta_{m,n} = [n \leq m]$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac n{2^n}=\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,\frac {nx^{n-1}}{2^n}=\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,\frac1{2^n}\frac{d}{dx}\!x^n=\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,\frac1{2^n}\!x^n=\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x/2}{1-x/2}=\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x}{2-x}=\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{d}{dx}\left(-1+\frac{2}{2-x}\right)=\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{2}{(2-x)^2}=2.
$$
Above the second equality is justified by Abel's Convergence Theorem, and the exchange of the series and the derivative by the uniform convergence of the power series and the series of the derivatives for $|x|<2$.

On the other hand,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac1{2^n}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2^{k-1}}=2\,\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2^k}=2
$$