# Prove that $\sum_i\sum_j a_{ij}=\sum_j\sum_i a_{ij}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that $\sum_i\sum_j a_{ij}=\sum_j\sum_i a_{ij}$ if $a_{ij}$ >=0

All I could come up with so far is that for power series, we could try to prove this using multiplication rule but again I am not sure. I don't see how the order would matter in a power series.

Comment: Addition is associative and commutative, so for finite summation limits, these properties are all you need. In fact, it doesn't even matter if $a_{ij}$ is nonnegative. So this makes me think there's something about the limits of the summations that you're not explaining. Could you provide more context?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497096/does-this-hold-sum-n-1-infty-sum-k-1n-2-n-sum-k-1-infty-sum-n/497120#497120

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien : you're kind of missing my point here. I'm trying to get the OP to ask the question more explicitly, like in the question that you linked.

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of Tonelli's theorem.